# stack exception handling and destructors unwinding. How to use the information

Tags: c++, exception, gcc

In my program I have a garbage collector and I need to track which objects are kept on local variables in my program in order to avoid to garbage collect them while these are alive.

While I have used a linked list creating a composite type, I just realized after years that the C++ language must keep that linked list for it's own destructor purposes related especially to exception handling.

So I am thinking to simplify my code by using that information kept by the C++ exception handler. Is there a portable way to do it ?

If not is there information on that at least for g++ and clang ?

By the way as I am using multitasking I should be able to do it for every task (these are waiting when the garbage collector runs).

What I exactly need is to traverse the local variables that have a destructor set up (and do that in a non destructive way).

Comment: "In my program I have a garbage collector" - stop. This is already an error. c++ uses RAII which makes garbage collection un-necessary. Java and c# have garbage collection, and that's an error too - but they're too far down the track to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a destructor is for. If you need to know when an object, whether on the heap, or on the stack, goes out of scope, then you would use a destructor for this.

Comment: As I already said, I have already used a composite object with a linked list and a destructor attached. The problem is that the same information is already kept by the C++ exception handling code somehow. So I would like to use that information in order to avoid: efficiency degradation, errors related to the fact of declaring an object as the simple type instead of the composite, and coding simpliicity.

Comment: The C++ exception handling code uses this information to destroy the objects and invoke the destructors. Typical C++ compilers implement this as a singly-linked list of <previous frame, address> tuples, that point to the previous stack frame, and the address of code that invokes the compiled destructor. This is not directly usable in C++, and correct way to use this information is, as I wrote, to properly implement your destructors.

Answer (score 0):

By examining the code emitted by the gnu gcc compiler, I found that the information regarding which destructors are to be executed is "saved" in code form id est the code knows what it has to destruct and takes care of it. So it is too diffult to get that information back.

The implementation could had been different and the code could had pushed into the processor stack as a return address the address of the destructor code along with the address of the struct instance.

So I was ready to abandon the effort but I found another hacky route.

I noticed that the gnu compiler, aligns structures on the stack on boundaries of 16 bytes.
As my structure is 8 bytes, there are 8 more unused bytes.
So I thought I could use them in order to keep track of objects allocated on the stack.
It must be said that depending on the compilation flags as -m64, -mx32 things change and changes must be taken care of.

Any way I managed to have the code bellow compile and work in both -m64 and -mx32 modes.

It isn't pure "C++" (exactly the opposite) but the code works and has the intended effect.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ONSTACK(x) (((size_t)x)&0xf0000000)==0xf0000000
struct A;
void* P=nullptr;

struct A{
    static int i;
    long long a;
    A(){
        if(ONSTACK(this)){
            *(void**)(this+1)=P;
            P=(void*)(this+1);
        }
        printf("this=%p\n",this);
        a=0x1111111111111111*i;i++;
    }
    ~A(){
        if(ONSTACK(this))
            P=*(void**)(this+1);
            *(void**)(this+1)=nullptr;
        a=0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;}
};

int A::i=0xA;
void* p;

void r1(){
    A x;int xx=0x66666666;
    A y;int yy=0x77777777;
    A z;int zz=0x88888888;
    int b=0x2222222222222222;
    printf("hello world %p\n",&b);

    for(void* i=P;i!=nullptr;i=*(void**)i){
        printf("a=%llX\n",(((A*)i)-1)->a);
    }
}

void r2(){
    long long r2a;
    r2a=0x3333333333333333;
    r1();
}

A A0;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   int i;p=(char*)&i-0x100;
    printf("sizeof(P)=%i\n",sizeof(P));
    r2();
}
```